# VSCode and Venvs: Unable to run pip install

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip, python-import, python-venv

I am running Python 3.9 in Visual Studio Code on Win10. I am trying to import BeautifulSoup (bs4) into a venv, but no luck. I get the following errors:

- During editing, Pylance says: Import "bs4" could not be resolved from source Pylance
- When running Python from VSCode "Play" button, I get a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

But I have previously installed bs4 using the terminal! When I enter

```
python3 -m pip install bs4
```

, I get "requirement already satisfied". What can be the problem? I am using a VENV in VSCode, and it is activated in the terminal and selected as the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution to my problem was to install bs4 not globally, but locally in the venv. Instead of running

```
python3 -m pip install bs4
```

simply run

```
pip install bs4
```

in a terminal that has the VENV activated. If the VENV is not activated, I can CD into .venv/Scripts and run

```
.\activate.ps1
```

(for windows PowerShell).